# Правильное использование global в threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, переменные-среды

Использую многопоточность, и возникла проблема.
В функции вызываемой при создании потока я использую другие функции, и чтобы не мучаться с передачей нужных ресурсов в качестве аргументов, я использую *global*. Но вот только проблема в том что global действует на главный поток, и в таком случае при задержке в первом потоке могут использоваться ресурсы другого.

Как сделать ресурсы глобальными только в одном потоке?

Comment: "Правильное использование global" - это не использовать `global`. Это плохой стиль и рано или поздно грабли вас настигнут.

Comment: Уже настигли...

Comment: Ну вот и сделайте лучше сразу нормально. Даже если сейчас удастся победить, потом всё-равно какой-нибудь ещё косяк вылезет.

Comment: каждый раз передавать аргументы будет неправильно по моему мнению, ладно если бы это была 1 функция, но их у меня больше десятка

Comment: А в чём проблема передать аргументы хоть в 100500 функций? Используйте списки и списковые сокращения, например. Всё решаемо в рамках питона, он прекрасно масштабируется в этом плане.

Comment: но ведь можно не переписывать большую часть кода а просто найти способ сделать глобальной переменную только в одном потоке...

Comment: Послушайте, передача аргументов заставит меня переписать довольно много кода,, аргументов много и функций тоже. Может на asyncio будет решение?

Comment: asyncio - хороший вариант, но не зная деталей вашей программы как можно что-то советовать? Да, многопоточность, упирающаяся в ввод-вывод должна делаться на async методах, в питоне это обычно asyncio, да

Comment: В функцию при создании потока передается один и главный аргумент, далее создаются новые по типу чтение из базы данных. Мне нужно чтобы эти аргументы оставались глобальными лишь в потоке, при каждой функции чтение будет затрачивать больше памяти, передавать каждый будет неудобно

Answer (score 0):

Как и предполагал, решение заключалось в смене `threading` на `multiprocessing`.
В дочернем потоке глобальные переменные передаются в основной, а в процессе нет.

*все точно как я и хотел, не переписывая большой части кода, и не передавая аргументы в каждую функцию*

Comment: жаль что сразу мне этого не сказали, потратил лишь время.